# What is the role of the Promise in the Prisma update and delete mutation?

Tags: reactjs, prisma

I am trying to figure out how to make a react app using prisma, where my schema has a relationship between two models. I have Issues and Issue Groups. Issues belong to Issue Groups.

The schema models are:

```
model Issue {
  id              String      @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  title           String
  description     String
  issueGroup      IssueGroup  @relation(fields: [issueGroupId], references: [id])
  issueGroupId    String      @db.Uuid
  createdAt       DateTime    @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt       DateTime    @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)
}

model IssueGroup {
  id              String @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  title           String
  description     String
  issues          Issue[]
  createdAt       DateTime @default(now()) @db.Timestamptz(6)
  updatedAt       DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)
}
```

I made an issueGroup.resolver.ts as follows:

```
import { Arg, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { IssueGroup } from "./issueGroup.model"
import { IssueGroupService } from "./issueGroup.service"
import { IssueGroupInput } from "./inputs/create.input"
import { Inject, Service } from "typedi"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => IssueGroup)
export default class IssueGroupResolver {
    @Inject(() => IssueGroupService)
        issueGroupService: IssueGroupService

    @Query(() => [IssueGroup])
        async issueGroups() {
            return await this.issueGroupService.getAllIssueGroups()
        }
    
    @Query(() => IssueGroup)
    async issueGroup(@Arg("id") id: string) {
        return await this.issueGroupService.getIssueGroup(id)
    }

    @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    async createIssueGroup(@Arg("data") data: IssueGroupInput) {
        return await this.issueGroupService.createIssueGroup(data)
    }
        // : Promise<IssueGroup[]> {

    
    // private readonly issueGroupService: IssueGroupService
    
    // @Query(() => [IssueGroup])
    // async issueGroups(): Promise<IssueGroup[]> {
    //     return this.issueGroupService.findAll()
    // }
    
    // @Query(() => IssueGroup)
    // async issueGroup(@Arg("id") id: string): Promise<IssueGroup> {
    //     return this.issueGroupService.findOne(id)
    // }
    
    // @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    // async createIssueGroup(
    //     @Arg("data") data: IssueGroupInput
    // ): Promise<IssueGroup> {
    //     return this.issueGroupService.create(data)
    // }
    
    @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    async updateIssueGroup(
        @Arg("id") id: string,
        @Arg("data") data: IssueGroupInput
    ): Promise<IssueGroup> {
        return this.issueGroupService.updateIssueGroup(id, data)
    }
    
    @Mutation(() => IssueGroup)
    async deleteIssueGroup(@Arg("id") id: string): Promise<IssueGroup> {
        return this.issueGroupService.deleteIssueGroup(id)
    }
}
```

I made an issueGroup.service.ts as follows:

```
import { prisma } from "../../lib/prisma"
import { Service } from "typedi"
import { IssueGroupInput } from "./inputs/create.input"

import { Resolver } from "type-graphql"
import { IssueGroup } from "./issueGroup.model"

@Service()
@Resolver(() => IssueGroup)
export class IssueGroupService {
  async createIssueGroup(data: IssueGroupInput) {
    return await prisma.issueGroup.create({
      data,
    })
  }

  async deleteIssueGroup(id: string) {
    return await prisma.issueGroup.delete({ where: { id } })
  }

  async updateIssueGroup(id: string, data: IssueGroupInput) {
    const issueGroup = await prisma.issueGroup.findUnique({ where: { id } })
    if (!issueGroup) {
      throw new Error("Issue not found")
    }
    return await prisma.issueGroup.update({ where: { id }, data })
  }

  async getAllIssueGroups() {
    return await prisma.issueGroup.findMany()
  }

  async getIssueGroup(id: string) {
    return await prisma.issueGroup.findUnique({
      where: {
        id,
      },
    })
  }
}
```

The issueGroup.model.ts has:

```
import * as Prisma from "@prisma/client"
import { Field, ObjectType } from "type-graphql"

import { BaseModel } from "../shared/base.model"

@ObjectType()
export class IssueGroup extends BaseModel implements Prisma.IssueGroup {
  @Field()
  title: string

  @Field()
  description: string

  @Field()
  issues: Prisma.Issue[];
}
```

The update mutation in the issueGroup resolver is throwing an error on the basis that type issue is missing in the import for issueGroup (it's in the issueGroup model to hold the array of issues that belong to an issue group).

Both the update and delete mutations give an error that says:

> issueGroup is not assignable to type import (then lists the address of
> the file with the model).IssueGroup.

I tried changing the issue field in the issueGroup.model.ts to:

```
@Field(type => String)
  issues: Prisma.Issue[];
```

But that doesn't make the error go away.  The exact language of the error message for the update resolver mutation in vsCode is:

> Property 'issues' is missing in type
> 'import("/.../node_modules/.prisma/client/index").IssueGroup' but
> required in type
> 'import("/.../src/modules/issueGroup/issueGroup.model").IssueGroup'.ts(2741)
> issueGroup.model.ts(15, 3): 'issues' is declared here.

The error message for the delete mutation is:

> [{    "resource": "/.../src/modules/issueGroup/issueGroup.resolver.ts",
> "owner": "typescript",  "code": "2322",     "severity": 8,  "message":
> "Type 'import("/.../node_modules/.prisma/client/index").IssueGroup'
> is not assignable to type
> 'import("/.../src/modules/issueGroup/issueGroup.model").IssueGroup'.",
> "source": "ts",     "startLineNumber": 59,  "startColumn": 9,
> "endLineNumber": 59,    "endColumn": 59 }]

How can I update the issueGroup to either add or remove an issue from the issueGroup object or if I delete the issueGroup, to also delete the Issue?

**STRANGE INSIGHT**

The VS code error messages go away if I delete the sections of the update and delete mutations that say:

```
: Promise<IssueGroup>
```

This component of the mutation was recommended by github copilot. No explanation as to why. How can I find out what it means and does?

Comment: The Promise in the Prisma update and delete mutation serves as a placeholder for the asynchronous operation of updating or deleting an issue group in the database. This allows the resolver to return a resolved value when the update or delete operation has completed, ensuring that the correct data is returned to the client.

Comment: so should I put it back and tolerate the error in VS code? Or is there a different way to express this component of the code block?